# Changing "show" and "edit" for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in routes:

```
resources :resource1
```

I want to add a parameter to "edit" and "show" in the url and only to "edit" and "show". Say, I want to add a date to the url so it'll look like "resource1/2016-05-12/123" for "show". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude routes from the `resources` definition:

```
resources :resource1, except: [:edit, :show]
```

Then write custom definitions for those routes:

```
get "/resource/:date/:id", to: "resource1#show"
put "/resource/:date/:id", to: "resource1#edit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  resource1:  '/resource1',
  resource2:  '/resource2'
}
.each do |c_name, path|
  controller c_name, path: path do
    scope path: ':id/:date' do
      put action: :edit
      get action: :show
    end
  end
end
```